# Image not drawing on player

Tags: javascript, html, css

Problem here is I am trying to draw an image on my player and it is not showing up. On my last program I did this the same way and it showed up. Am I doing something wrong here? Everything is linked to the specific folder and named correctly.

```
function GameObject(obj)
{   
        this.x = canvas.width/2;
        this.y = canvas.height/2;
        this.width = 100;
        this.height = 100;
        this.color = "#A9A9A9";
        this.force = 1;
        this.ax = 1;
        this.ay = 1;
        this.vx = 0;
        this.vy = 0;


        //------Allows us to pass object literals into the class to define its properties--------//
        //------This eliminate the need to pass in the property arguments in a specific order------------//
        if(obj!== undefined)
        {
            for(value in obj)
            {
                if(this[value]!== undefined)
                this[value] = obj[value];
            }
        }


    //whether or not the object can jump
    this.canJump = false;
    this.jumpHeight = -25;


    this.drawRect = function()
    {
        context.save();
            context.fillStyle = this.color;
            context.translate(this.x, this.y);
            context.fillRect((-this.width/2), (-this.height/2), this.width, this.height);
        context.restore();

    }   

    this.drawCircle = function()
    {
        context.save();
            context.fillStyle = this.color;
            context.beginPath();
            context.translate(this.x, this.y);
            context.arc(0, 0, this.radius(), 0, 360 *Math.PI/180, true);
            context.closePath();
            context.fill();
        context.restore();

    }   

    this.move = function()
    {
        this.x += this.vx;
        this.y += this.vy;
    }


    //---------Returns object's for the top, bottom, left and right of an object's bounding box.
    this.left = function() 
    {
        return {x:this.x - this.width/2 , y:this.y}
    }
    this.right = function() 
    {
        return {x:this.x + this.width/2 , y:this.y}
    }

    this.top = function() 
    {
        return {x:this.x, y:this.y - this.height/2}
    }
    this.bottom = function() 
    {
        return {x:this.x , y:this.y + this.height/2}
    }

    this.hitTestObject = function(obj)
    {
        if(this.left().x <= obj.right().x && 
           this.right().x >= obj.left().x &&
           this.top().y <= obj.bottom().y &&
           this.bottom().y >= obj.top().y)
        {
            return true
        }
        return false;
    }

    //------Tests whether a single point overlaps the bounding box of another object-------
    this.hitTestPoint = function(obj)
    {
        if(obj.x >= this.left().x && 
           obj.x <= this.right().x &&
           obj.y >= this.top().y &&  
           obj.y <= this.bottom().y)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /*-----Sets or gets the radius value--------*/
    this.radius = function(newRadius)
    {
         if(newRadius==undefined)
         {
            return this.width/2; 
         }
         else
         {
             return newRadius;
         }
    }

    //Draws the collision points
    this.drawDebug = function()
    {
        var size = 5;
        context.save();
        context.fillStyle = "black";
        context.fillRect(this.left().x-size/2, this.left().y-size/2, size, size);
        context.fillRect(this.right().x-size/2, this.right().y-size/2, size, size);
        context.fillRect(this.top().x-size/2, this.top().y-size/2, size, size);
        context.fillRect(this.bottom().x-size/2, this.bottom().y-size/2, size, size);
        context.fillRect(this.x-size/2, this.y-size/2, size, size);
        context.restore();
    }
}
```

```js
//Declare my variables

var canvas;
var context;
var timer;
var interval;
var player;

var screenWidth;
var screenHeight;

var gameState;
var gameOverMenu;
var restartButton;

var img = document.getElementById("light");






canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
context = canvas.getContext("2d");



//lose screen
function gameInitialize() {
  var canvas = document.getElementByID("game-screen");
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
  screenHeight = window.innerHeight;

  canvas.width = screenWidth;
  canvas.height = screenHeight;

  document.addEventListener("keydown", keyboardHandler);

  gameOverMenu = document.getElementByID("gameOver")
  centerMenuPosition(gameOverMenu);


  restartButton = document.getElementByID("restartButton");
  restartButton.addEventListener("click".gameRestart);

  setState("PLAY");






  //lose screen 
}

function setState(state) {
  gameState = state;
  showMenu(state);

}

function displayMenu(menu) {
  menu.style.visibility = "visible";



}

function showMenu(state) {
  if (state == "GAME OVER") {
    displayMenu(gameOverMenu);


  }



}

//restart for lose screen
function gameRestart() {

  if (player.y > 0) {

    setState("GAME OVER");




  }
}





player = new GameObject();

//my platforms
platform0 = new GameObject();
platform0.width = 500;
platform0.y = player.y + player.height / 2 + platform0.height / 2;
platform0.color = "#000B12";


/* platform1 = new GameObject();
    platform1.width = 50;
    platform1.height = 300;
    platform1.y = platform0.y - platform0.height/2 - platform1.height/2;
    platform1.x = platform0.x-platform0.width/2;
    platform1.color = "000B12"; */


platform1 = new GameObject();
platform1.width = 50;
platform1.height = 300;
platform1.y = platform0.y - platform0.height / 2 - platform1.height / 2;
platform1.x = platform1.x - platform0.width / 2;
platform1.color = "000B12";


platform2 = new GameObject();
platform2.width = 50;
platform2.height = 300;
platform2.y = platform0.y - platform0.height / 2 - platform2.height / 2;
platform2.x = platform0.x + platform0.width / 2;
platform2.color = "000B12";

platform3 = new GameObject();
platform3.width = 50;
platform3.height = 300;
platform3.y = platform0.y - platform0.height / 2 - platform2.height / 2;
platform3.x = platform2.x + platform0.width / 2;
platform3.color = "000B12";

/* platform3 = new GameObject();
    platform3.width = 300;
    platform3.height = 50;
    platform3.y = platform2.y;
    platform3.x = platform2.x ;
    platform3.color = "000B12"; */

platform4 = new GameObject();
platform4.width = 50
platform4.height = 300
platform4.y = platform0.y - platform0.height / 2 - platform4.height / 2;
platform4.x = platform0.x + platform0.width / 2;
platform4.color = "008000";

platform5 = new GameObject();
platform5.width = 50
platform5.height = 300
platform5.y = platform0.y - platform0.height / 2 - platform4.height / 2;
platform5.x = platform0.x + platform0.width / 2;
platform5.color = "000B12";

//This platform uses an object literal to define the properties
platform4 = new GameObject({
  width: 300,
  height: 50,
  y: platform2.y,
  color: "#000B12"
});

//Global Physics Variables
var fX = .97;
var fY = .97;

var gravity = 1;

interval = 1000 / 60;
timer = setInterval(animate, interval);


//animate for player etc.   
function animate() {

  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);


  //Jump with the w key
  if (w && player.canJump) {
    player.canJump = false;
    player.vy += player.jumpHeight;
  }

  //Apply acceleration to velocity.
  if (a) {
    player.vx += -player.ax * player.force;
  }
  if (d) {
    player.vx += player.ax * player.force;
  }

  player.vx *= fX;
  player.vy *= fY;

  player.vy += gravity;

  player.x += Math.round(player.vx);
  player.y += Math.round(player.vy);

  //Hit the ground
  while (platform0.hitTestPoint(player.bottom()) && player.vy >= 0) {
    player.y--;
    player.vy = 0;
    player.canJump = true;
  }

  /* while(platform1.hitTestPoint(player.left()))
  {
    player.x++;
    player.vx = 0;
  } */

  while (platform2.hitTestPoint(player.right())) {
    player.x--;
    player.vx = 0;
  }

  /* while(platform3.hitTestPoint(player.top()))
  {
    player.y++;
    player.vy = 0;
  }
  while(platform3.hitTestPoint(player.bottom()) && player.vy >=0)
  {
    player.y--;
    player.vy = 0;
    player.canJump = true;
  } */

  while (platform4.hitTestPoint(player.bottom()) && player.vy >= 0) {
    player.y--;
    player.vy = 0;
    player.canJump = true;

  }

  // Light on player

  //draw light
  context.drawImage(img, player.x - player.width / 2, player.y - player.height / 2, player.width, player.height);

  platform0.drawRect();
  platform1.drawRect();
  platform2.drawRect();
  platform3.drawRect();

  platform4.drawRect();
  player.drawRect();

  //Show hit points
  player.drawDebug();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #0C0D0D;
}

#gameOver {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="author" content="Robs">
  <title>Robs proto game</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="800">
        Your browser is outdated and does not support HTML5. Please update to the latest version.
    <img src="images/Light.png" alt="Light source" id="light">
    </canvas>
  <section id="gameOver">
    <h1 class="title"> GAME OVER! </h1>
    <h3 id="restartButton">Restart? </h3>


  </section>


</body>
<!--Controls-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controls.js"></script>
<!--Classes-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Classes/GameObject.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/basic_platformer.js"></script>

</html>
```

I get no errors when running. Everything runs and I can play my game but cannot see the image that I am trying to produce onto the player.

Comment: I get this error running your snip: {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: GameObject is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 150,
  "colno": 1
}

Comment: I added my GameObject.js that is working with it to define my game objects.

Comment: Hello @Rob. When running your whole code it complains about the w variables not being specified `//Jump with the w key
  if (w && player.canJump) {`
Maybe it's also a good idea to present your running code in [Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/) or [CodePen](https://codepen.io/) so others can see it running.